# Multiple work request in Work Manager for Periodic task

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a task to synchronize Room DB data to the server every 2 hours in the background, for that the best option I found is Work Manager, but there is a problem I have two tables one for images and the second for the form data, first Worker Task is to upload all the images to the server using Retrofit Multipart and then upload form data from another table.
There are basically need two worker classes and I don't know to arrange them to complete the whole task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle this.

1. Use the same `Worker` to handle both use cases like -

```kotlin
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    // uploading images
    withContext(Dispatcher.IO) { uploadImages() }

    // uploading form data
    withContext(Dispatcher.IO) { uploadFormData() }

    return Result.success()
}
```

2. Enqueue `FormDataUploadWorker` after the `ImageUploadWorker` is finished
   (Not recommended though):

```kotlin
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    // assuming there is some sort of result returned
    val isSuccess = withContext(Dispatcher.IO) { uploadImages() }

    if (isSuccess) {
        // Should be OneTimeWorkRequest, better if it is expedited
        WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).enqueue(FormDataUploadWorker)
    }

    return Result.success()
}
```

3. WorkManager also supports chained tasks (recommended, IMO).

```kotlin
WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
    .beginWith(ImageUploadWorker)
    .then(FormDataUploadWorker)
    .enqueue()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, I have little confusion about the Work Manager is when should I schedule the worker request means in the Application class, or on the Home page. Actually, this request is not directly handled by the user input it should run in the background without any user involvement.

Comment: I suggest scheduling in the `Application` class, but make sure to use `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP` so as to not delete & reschedule tasks on every app open or `Application.onCreate()`.

Comment: Sure, also accept the answer if it helped.